# Extjs tree not able to load nested object

Tags: object, extjs, tree, nested

I have a class called Zone1s in java which has  2 fields text(name of zone) and list of Zone1s.
when  i convert it to json i get following response :

```
{"text":"Papa","Zone1s":[{"text":"Beta1","Zone1s":[{"text":"BetaBeta1","Zone1s":[]},{"text":"BetaBeta2","Zone1s":[]}]},{"text":"Beta2","Zone1s":[]}]}
```

i wrote a Extjs model,store and panel below:

```
Ext.define('Zone1s', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [

        { name: 'text', type: 'string' } 
    ], 

    proxy: {                       
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'test.htm',
        reader: {
    type  : 'json',
      record: 'Zone1s'
        }
    },
hasMany: {model: 'Zone1s', name: 'Zone1s'},
belongsTo: 'Zone1s'
});

var store =Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Zone1s',
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

i am getting following error:
**me.store.getRootNode is not a function...**
Can anyone please Guide me where i am wrong ?
 i have gone through 
[How do I show nested data into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632363/extjs-4-how-do-i-show-nested-data-into-a-tree)
 but here my Zone1s can have Zone1s in themselves that's the difference.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a root attribute to your Store :

```
var store =Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Zone1s',
    autoLoad: true,
    root: {
      text: 'Zone1s',
      id: 'Zone1s',
      expanded: true
   }
});
```

If you do not want to see the root node, use the *rootVisible* attribute :

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        store: store,
        rootVisible : false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```